# How can I prevent users from delete files/folders but can add/modify on linux?

Tags: linux, centos

I have a folder `my_folder` which contains files and folders

```
my_folder
|-- my_sub_folder
|   |-- my_file_1.txt
|
|-- my_file_2.txt
|-- my_sub_folder_2
|   |-- my_file_2.txt
```

I want to set permissions that user can add/modify files and directories to `my_folder` but not be able delete anything in it. It's sort of write-only permissions.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you make the directories world writable and set the sticky bit on them other users will be able to create new files but will only have write access to the files they own.

From `man chmod`:

> The sticky bit prevents unprivileged users from removing or renaming a file in the directory unless they own the file or the directory; this is called the restricted deletion flag for the directory, and  is  commonly  found  on world-writable  directories  like /tmp.

For example, as root:

```
# cd my_folder
# find . -type d | xargs chmod 1777
```

Sticky bit permission shows up as `t` in `ls`'s output:

```
# ls -ld my_folder
drwxrwxrwt 4 root root 4096 2014-12-01 18:52 my_folder
```

Now as regular user:

```
$ cd my_folder
$ echo foo > user_file     # ok
$ rm user_file             # ok
$ rm  -f my_sub_folder/my_file_1.txt
rm: cannot remove `my_sub_folder/my_file_1.txt': Operation not permitted
```